# "It claims to be" vs "it claims is"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> A. The company has unveiled what it claims **is** the world's smallest
> camera.
>
> B. The company has unveiled what it claims **to be** the world's
> smallest camera.

Could someone please explain why sentence A is correct and not B?

I have tried to split it:

> C. The company has unveiled something.
>
> D. The company claims that this something **is** the world's smallest camera.

I can understand the use of "is" in sentence D, but sentence A still sounds bizarre to my ears.

All this time I have always thought that "claim" must be followed by "to be".  Could someone please explain when to use "claim to be" and when to use "claim is" ?

Comment: Interesting question. It seems a matter of conjugation of _to be_. Both seem right to me.

Comment: Who says 'B' is not correct? I think that both A and B are grammatical and in current use.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. The company has unveiled what it claims **is** the world's smallest camera.
> 2. The company has unveiled what it claims **to be** the world's smallest camera.

### **Short answer**

Both of the Original Poster's examples are in fact grammatical. However, the first sentence is arguably slightly preferable to the second because,  for reasons explored in the full answer below, it is a bit easier to process.

---

### **Full answer**

**How the sentences work**

The verb *CLAIM*, like the verb *FIND*, for example, can take a number of different types of Complement. Amongst others it can take a finite clause or a non-finite clause—usually with the verb *BE*—as Complement:

- The group claim (that) Bob is an impostor. <sup>[finite clause with tensed verb]</sup>
- The group claim Bob to be an impostor. <sup>[non-finite clause with infinitive construction]</sup>

We can compare this with:

- The group found (that) the strawberry flavour was the best.
- The group found the strawberry flavour to be the best.

We can show how the Original Poster's examples are constructed. These sentences use fused relative constructions using the relative word *what*. We can understand this word to mean something like *the thing which* or *a thing which*. We can model the sentences like this:

- The company has unveiled what<sub>(i)</sub> it claims [ __<sub>(i)</sub> is the world's smallest camera].
- The company has unveiled what<sub>(i)</sub> it claims [ __<sub>(i)</sub> to be the world's smallest camera].

In the sentences above, the gap is identified as representing the same thing as the relative word, *what*. We could also model the sentences like this:

- The company unveiled a thing which it claims [ <s>this thing</s> is the world's smallest camera].
- The company unveiled a thing which it claims [ <s>this thing</s> to be the world's smallest camera].

Both of these sentences are grammatically correct and meaningful. However there is one reason why we might prefer the first to the second.

**A processing issue**

As was mentioned in Sunlight's answer post here (now deleted), the verb *CLAIM* can function as a control verb. This means that when it takes a non-finite clause without a Subject, our interpretation of the Subject in the subordinate, clause is determined by the Subject of the main clause (the matrix clause). The verb *FIND* is not a control verb and does not work in this way:

- Bob claims to be telepathic.
- *Bob found to be telepathic. (ungrammatical).

The second example above is ungrammatical. In the first, we understand the Subject of *to be telepathic* to be the Subject of the main clause, *Bob*. We can model the sentence like this:

- Bob<sub>(i)</sub> claims [<s>himself</s><sub>(i)</sub> to be telepathic].

Now, in terms of the current question this has some minor significance. Consider the beginning of the following sentence:

- The company has unveiled what it claims to be ....

Here we can instantly see that there is no overt Subject of the verb in the subordinate clause. However, we do not know if this missing Subject is a gap from a relative clause, or if it is meant to be being controlled by the Subject of the main clause. In other words, the beginning of this sentence is ambiguous. It could mean either:

- The company has unveiled a thing which the company claims [the company to be ... ]
- The company has unveiled a thing which the company claims [this thing to be ... ]

For example the sentence could unfold as either of the following:

- The company has unveiled what it claims to be most heavily reliant upon.
- The company has unveiled what it claims to be its biggest loss.

The Subject of *to be* in the first sentence is understood as the company itself. The Subject of *to be* in the second is understood as being the thing which was unveiled.

This shows that the beginning of the Original Poster's second sentence is slightly ambiguous. We cannot tell what the Subject of the non-finite clause is until we finish reading the sentence. Although it is a grammatical sentence, there *is* a slight possibility for the reader to parse the sentence in the wrong way when they start reading it. They may possibly have to backtrack or even read the sentence again.

This cannot happen with the Original Poster's first sentence. We only find Subject control in non-finite subordinate clauses, not finite ones. With a normal finite clause, the Subject must be present and cannot be controlled by the Subject of a higher clause:

- *I claim am the best saxophonist.

The sentence above is ungrammatical because the Subject of *am* is missing. We cannot use the sentence above to mean:

- I claim I am the best saxophonist.

When we read the Original Poster's first sentence, we know that the gap in front of *to be* must be caused by the relative clause construction. We know that the Subject of *to be* is the same thing referred to by the word *what*.

For this reason, some readers (myself included) might find the first sentence slightly  better than the second. Of course this does not mean that it is *more grammatical*.

**Conclusion**

Both the Original Poster's examples are grammatical. However, some readers may find the first easier to parse than the second.

Comment: Done. BTW, Do you think there's a semantic difference between the two constructions, _I claim that X is Y_ and _I claim X to be Y_? Isn't the first one a stronger claim, for example?

Comment: @Fard I think the second sounds more formal, but I'm not sure whether there's any substantial difference in meaning. I'm not sure though. Maybe someone can find an example where there would be.

Comment: You missed out [The group claim Bob **as** their inspiration](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22claim+him+as+their+inspiration%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, and you missed "amongst others" ;-)  Yes, I didn't cover them all. There's so many!

Comment: *?The group claim Bob to be their inspiration.* This sounds odd to me. I would correct it in a paper. For me, *claim* cannot be used with an accusative with infinitive like this.

Comment: @Cerberus [Here's a load of examples for you](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22caim+Jesus+to+be%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=aMr2VvIRgvdSqripwA0#q=%22claim+Jesus+to+be%22)

Comment: @Cerberus [Some more](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22caim+Jesus+to+be%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=aMr2VvIRgvdSqripwA0#tbm=bks&q=%22claim+them+to+be%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Though I'd have to agree that I'd prefer your construction for that particular sentence by far ...

Comment: @Cerberus In other words I claim them to be perfectly valid constructions! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria Why do you prefer the construction with _as_? If it's so much better, then maybe it's not a bad idea to offer it as an alternative option in your answer.

Comment: @Cerberus,Araucaria: In other words ***I*** claim them ***as*** perfectly valid constructions! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria: Meh, the fact that some people use it doesn't mean it isn't ugly...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: With *as*, it sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @Araucaria The reasoning aside, I don't know how much truth is in your argument that the first sentence is preferable. For example, here's an ngram that says otherwise: http://bit.ly/1Mx5YUi

Comment: @JK2 That Ngram's no good as a measure of this because, as pointed out in my post *what it claims to be* is ambiguous and is likely to refer to *what it claims it is* and not *what it claims is*. So the very first result you come to, for example under 1980-2000 is *Manifestly, obstetrics is not what it claims to be*, where the Subject of *to be* is *obstetrics*.

Comment: @Cerberus "Meh, the fact that some people use it doesn't mean it isn't ugly..." <--- Agreed.

Comment: @JK2 And, actually, nine of the ten results on the first page from 1980-2000 are of that type, where the Subject of *claim* is also the Subject of *to be*. Let me know what you think  ...

Comment: I like this - the introduction of ellipsis into the analysis focuses the discussion well.

Comment: @Araucaria You're right that _what it claims to be_ can be ambiguous. But are you sure about the nine of the ten results being of that type? When I looked at that first page, it was more like seven of the ten. The second, fourth and the tenth were of the other type. Am I mistaken about this? Meantime, the ratio between the two forms during '80-'00 is more like 6, as shown in this ngram: http://bit.ly/22L9fXR

Comment: @JK2 No, your definitely right about the three, I was looking too quickly. You can't really tell much from the ratio though, it seems to me, because for example, there'd  be no ambiguity when the complement of the verb is *so*, for example, or other times when the VP's very short (i.e. *the case*). But I don't really understand what you did with that last Ngram ...

Comment: @Araucaria All the ngram shows is that _what it claims to be_ is **6 times** more frequently used than _what it claims it is_ during that period. So what I was trying to say, albeit inconclusively, was that, granted, only a small fraction (like 3 out of 10) of _what it claims to be_ has a different subject for _to be_ than _it_, but it's not statistically conclusive either that the latter is less frequent or less preferred than _what it claims it is_, given the ngram.

Comment: @JK2 But I don't claim that it is unpreferable when interpreted as *what it claims it is* I am only talking about *what it claims is* - and then only when the VP is long. I don't think your Ngram is very useful here, it seems to me.

Answer (score 5):

***[To claim](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/claim_1):***

> - To say something that is true although it has not been proved and other people may not believe it:

The verb claim can be used with the following constructions:

1) > -  ***claim (that)…*** He claims (that) he was not given a fair hearing.

2)> -  ***claim (somebody/something) to be/do something***  I don't claim to be an expert.

3) > - ***claim something*** Scientists are claiming a major breakthrough in the fight against cancer.

4) > - ***it is claimed that…*** It was claimed that some doctors were working 80 hours a week.

Your sentences:

- The company (has unveiled .....) claims (that the camera) is the world's smallest. (Example 1)
- The company ( has unveiled ...) claims (the camera) to be the world's smallest. ( Example 2).

Answer (score 2):

If an entity makes a claim about itself, it uses "to be." For example:

> The company claims **to be** the manufacturer of the world's smallest camera.

If an entity makes a claim about something else, it uses "is." For example:

> The company claims its camera **is** the smallest in the world.

If the camera could make a claim about itself, the following would be correct:

> The camera claims **to be** the world's smallest camera.

Comment: I disagree. To me, both *The company claims that it is the manufacturer of the world's smallest camera* and *The company claims its camera to be the smallest in the world* are perfectly grammatical.